# Vagrant box Debian/Stretch64 is not syncing in real time

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, debian-stretch

I have been trying to use the `debian/stretch64` box from Vagrant but its real-time sync does not work.

Here is the code of my `Vagrantfile`:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

HOSTNAME = "DebianStretch64"
VB_NAME = "DebianStretch64"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.hostname = HOSTNAME
  config.vm.box = "debian/stretch64"
  config.vm.define VB_NAME

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.name = VB_NAME
    end

end
```

When I run vagrant up on my Windows 10 I get:

```
PS C:\Users\Home\code\vagrantfiles\debian_stretch64> vagrant up
Bringing machine 'DebianStretch64' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> DebianStretch64: Importing base box 'debian/stretch64'...
==> DebianStretch64: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> DebianStretch64: Checking if box 'debian/stretch64' is up to date...
==> DebianStretch64: Setting the name of the VM: DebianStretch64
==> DebianStretch64: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> DebianStretch64: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> DebianStretch64: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    DebianStretch64: Adapter 1: nat
==> DebianStretch64: Forwarding ports...
    DebianStretch64: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> DebianStretch64: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> DebianStretch64: Booting VM...
==> DebianStretch64: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    DebianStretch64: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    DebianStretch64: SSH username: vagrant
    DebianStretch64: SSH auth method: private key
    DebianStretch64:
    DebianStretch64: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    DebianStretch64: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    DebianStretch64:
    DebianStretch64: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    DebianStretch64: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    DebianStretch64: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> DebianStretch64: Machine booted and ready!
==> DebianStretch64: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    DebianStretch64: No guest additions were detected on the base box for this VM! Guest
    DebianStretch64: additions are required for forwarded ports, shared folders, host only
    DebianStretch64: networking, and more. If SSH fails on this machine, please install
    DebianStretch64: the guest additions and repackage the box to continue.
    DebianStretch64:
    DebianStretch64: This is not an error message; everything may continue to work properly,
    DebianStretch64: in which case you may ignore this message.
==> DebianStretch64: Setting hostname...
==> DebianStretch64: Installing rsync to the VM...
==> DebianStretch64: Rsyncing folder: /cygdrive/c/Users/Home/code/vagrantfiles/debian_stretch64/ => /vagrant

==> DebianStretch64: Machine 'DebianStretch64' has a post `vagrant up` message. This is a message
==> DebianStretch64: from the creator of the Vagrantfile, and not from Vagrant itself:
==> DebianStretch64:
==> DebianStretch64: Vanilla Debian box. See https://app.vagrantup.com/debian for help and bug reports
```

Inside this vagrant, I create a new file test.txt inside the `/vagrant` folder:

```
PS C:\Users\Home\code\vagrantfiles\debian_stretch64> vagrant ssh
Linux DebianStretch64 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
vagrant@DebianStretch64:~$ cd /vagrant/
vagrant@DebianStretch64:/vagrant$ touch test.txt
vagrant@DebianStretch64:/vagrant$ ls
playbook.yaml  test.txt  Vagrantfile
```

However, I cannot find the file `test.txt` in the folder containing the `Vagrantfile`. When I use the `Ubuntu/Xenial64`, I do not experience this issue. Does someone have an idea how to solve it?

Regards,

Comment: I do not understand your question. When you run `ls`, it clearly shows that `test.txt` is in the same directory as `Vagrantfile`. What do you meany you cannot find it?

Comment: That's the point it is in '/vagrant' but not in the host

Comment: @HSS did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

If you need the Virtualbox shared folder functionality when using the Debian Boxes, you need to use the **debian/contrib-stretch64** boxes

Virtualbox shared folder is disabled on debian/stretch64 becauses this requires a non opensource package to add the specific virtualbox bits.

This is documented here:
https://app.vagrantup.com/debian